# How to define and stretch row height for x number of rows for UI Table View?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using a UITableView that only and will only ever have values in 10 rows. I would like to set the height of the 10 rows so it fills the view controller no matter what device is being used.

On the iPhone 4 it's showing 10 rows. The iPhone 5 12 rows and iPhone 7 14 rows. How do I set the row height so it only shows 10 rows no matter what device it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return self.view.bounds.size.height/10.0;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I actually used return (self.view.bounds.size.height -44) /10.0 to remove the height of my status bar but that worked perfect!

Comment: There's a better solution. When you want all rows to have the same height it is much better to set the table view's `rowHeight` property instead of implementing the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method. And the row height should be based on the table view's size (which will actually be `self.view` in a `UITableViewController`).